# Deleting redundant data inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem, I have this result below and I want to remove the same timestamp.

Sample Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => [1341100800000, 0]
[1] => [1341100800000,85]
[2] => [1343779200000,54]
[3] => [1343779200000, 0]
)
```

Expecting Output

```
Array
(
[0] => [1341100800000,85]
[1] => [1343779200000,54]
)
```

I'm thinking of using explode then substr function to get the value. Here is what I came up so far..

```
$explode = array();
    foreach($string_format as $key => $value) {
        $explode[] = explode(',', substr($value, 1));
        if((isset($explode[0]) && $explode[0][0] == $explode[1][0])) {
            unset($explode[0]);
        }
        //print_r($explode);

    }
```

Comment: what happened to the second value (0 and 85, 0 and 54)? what if there are another value, eg: 0, 85, and 95?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. How do you choose which duplicate value to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wouldn't this be a good use of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Yes, if there is no constraint in which of the duplicate values to keep (the OP doesn't mention one), a simple `array_unique($the_array, SORT_NUMERIC)` would work, exploiting that PHP converts the strings to numbers and discards anything after the `,`.

Comment: this is exactly what I've used.

Answer (score 2):

Script:

```
foreach($string_format as $key => $value) {
    $explode = explode(',', $value);
    $unique[$explode[0]] = $value;
}
```

Input:

```
$string_format = array('0' => '1341100800000, 0',
'1' => '1341100800000,85',
'2' => '1343779200000,54',
'3' => '1343779200000, 0');
```

Output:

```
$unique =
Array
(
    [1341100800000] => 1341100800000,85
    [1343779200000] => 1343779200000, 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine :)

```
    $explode = array();
    $timestmp = array();

   foreach($string_format as $key => $value) {
        $explode[$key] = explode(',', substr($value, 1));

        if( in_array( $explode[$key][0], $timestmp)) {
            unset ($explode[$key]);
        } else {
             $timestmp[]= $explode[$key][0];
        }
    }
```